# how to schedule a timed event in python

Tags: python, scheduler

I'd like to schedule a repeated timed event in python like this:
 "at time X launch function Y (in a separate thread) and repeat every hour"

"X" is fixed timestamp

The code should be cross-platform, so i'd like to avoid using an external program like "cron" to do this.

code extract:

```
    import threading
    threading.Timer(10*60, mail.check_mail).start()
    #... SET UP TIMED EVENTS HERE
    while(1):
        print("please enter command")
        try:
            command = raw_input()
        except:
            continue
        handle_command(command)
```

Comment: You need to provide more details about your application. Does it use an event loop, etc.

Comment: Why don't use `cron`? On windows people can use the task scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`dateutil.rrule`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57), `rr` for your schedule and then use a loop like this in your thread:

```
for ts in rr:
    now = datetime.now()
    if ts < now:
        time.sleep((now - ts).total_seconds())
    # do stuff
```

Or a better solution that will account for clock changes:

```
ts = next(rr)
while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    if ts < now:
        time.sleep((now - ts).total_seconds() / 2)
        continue
    # do stuff
    ts = next(rr)
```